# Python: cannot iterate over elements, if several identical elements stay in a row

Tags: python, arrays, unique-values

I'm a beginner, so sorry for such question.

I would like to iterate over the array and find unique values. However, it doesn't iterate further than "A". How could I solve it?

Thank you a lot in advance! Code ->

```
def letters_learned_today(word):
    unique_letters = []

    for letter in word:
        already_exists = False
        if letter in unique_letters:
            already_exists = True
            break
        else:
            unique_letters.append(letter)
    return unique_letters

word = 'AAABBVSCDDDERZAUJJFFPOUSST'
print(letters_learned_today(word))
```

---

Comment: just remove `break`

Comment: break makes you come out of the closest loop. You must know how to use break, pass, continue, and also understand use of loop and conditional statements. All the best.

Comment: you want to replace `break` with `continue` or leave it altogether

Comment: Thank you all very much for your comments and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
def letters_learned_today(word):
    unique_letters = []

    for letter in word:
        if letter not in unique_letters:
            unique_letters.append(letter)
    return unique_letters


word = "AAABBVSCDDDERZAUJJFFPOUSST"
print(letters_learned_today(word))
```